# Write a query using Union all that performs the function of UNION?

Tags: sql

Write a query using Union all that performs the function of UNION?

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL` returns all the records while `UNION` returns distinct records.

so you can use the `DISTINCT` with `UNION ALL` to make query same as `UNION` as follows:

```
select distinct t.* from
(select * from table1
UNION ALL
select * from table2) t
```

Comment: Note that unless `table1` and `table2` have a) the same number of columns, and b) the same types in order for all the columns, then your answer will not even run.  In general, using `SELECT *` with union queries is bad practice.

Comment: This is just to show the example of `UNION ALL` with `DISTINCT`. What you mentioned is correct but this is not what I wanted to highlight and considered as it is basic thing and OP must be knowing it